# Replacement for Drupal 6's $form_state['post'] in Drupal 7

Tags: forms

I have the following code (part of a module):

```
function whm_ui_edit_account_form($form, &$form_state, $account) {

  $res = whm_account_info($account);
  $account_data = $res[0];
  $current_state = array('values' => array(
    'user' => $account_data['user'],
    'domain' => $account_data['domain'],
    'email' => $account_data['email'],
    'plan' => $account_data['plan'],
  ));
  $form_state['values'] = array_merge($current_state['values'], $form_state['post']);

  $form = _whm_ui_account_form($form_state);
  $form['account']['password'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Change Password'),
    '#description' => t('Enter values here <b>ONLY</b> if you want to change this account\'s password.'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => empty($form_state['values']['pwd1']) && empty($form_state['values']['pwd2']),
  );
  $form['account']['password']['pwd1'] = $form['account']['pwd1'];
  $form['account']['password']['pwd1']['#required'] = FALSE;
  $form['account']['password']['pwd2'] = $form['account']['pwd2'];
  $form['account']['password']['pwd2']['#required'] = FALSE;
  unset($form['account']['pwd1']);
  unset($form['account']['pwd2']);
  unset($form['account']['email']);
  unset($form['account']['plan']);

  $form['current_user'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => $current_state['values']['user'],
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['current_domain'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => $current_state['values']['domain'],
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  return $form;
}
```

The $form_state['post'] no longer exists in D7 (I'm porting an old module) and perhaps I'm insanely tired or just out of my depth :-p but I can't find a suitable replacement. The function is essentially looking to merge existing information with the information given in the form before submitting (I think).

Any assistance or if anyone can point me to an alternative to the post value being used previously it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at `$form_state['input']`?

Comment: I haven't but I'll look into it and see what the effect is.

Comment: That did it JimaJamma - post that as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$form_state['post']` in Drupal 6 contains the values of the `$_POST` global, and a quick look at Drupal 7 shows that when accessing a form via the post method, `$form_state['input']` will contain that same array.  Side note: if it is accessed via the get method, this will contain `$_GET`.